# Injecting script into CefSharp

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

So I have this code from another article

```
    // Load the script
    var script = document.createElement("SCRIPT");
    script.src = 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/darkmode-js@1.5.5/lib/darkmode-js.min.js';
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.onload = function() {
        var $ = window.jQuery;
        // Use $ here...
    };
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
})();
```

Where do I add the code below to the above code

`new Darkmode({ label: '' }).showWidget();`

Comment: There's nothing specific about `CefSharp` in your question, best to remove the references and add some other tags, like `chrome` as the code will be exactly the same. You'll likely find people won't look at your question as it's too specific, where it doesn't need to be.

Comment: I understand but how can this be completed you know how do it I don’t please help.

Comment: There's a very large community who can help you out with generic javascript programming. I have limited time so need to focus on `CefSharp` related questions.The more time I spend answering generic questions the less time I have to answer specific `CefSharp` ones, then those questions would go unanswered.